# SCSS Override Value of Property from Class

Tags: css, sass, vuetify.js

i have this html

`<div class="v-menu__content" style="left: 559px;"></div>`

`<div class="v-menu__content" style="left: 12px;"></div>`

`<div class="v-menu__content" style="left: 1109px;"></div>`

is there a way in scss that i can override only the class
`v-menu__content`
with the `left: 12px`
and change the `12px` into `0.5rem !important`

these html are autogenerated by veutify under the hood so i have no control of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the attribute selector, although technically it is not what it is used for, but it can solve your problem in this example.
Here you go: `.v-menu__content[style*="left: 12px;"] {do your magic}`

```css
.v-menu__content[style*="left: 12px;"] {
  color: red;
  left: 0.5rem !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="v-menu__content" style="left: 559px;">test</div>
<div class="v-menu__content" style="left: 12px;">test</div>
<div class="v-menu__content" style="left: 1109px;">test</div>
```

Comment: thanks man.. didnt knew css can do some regex stuff

Answer (score 0):

If the `.v-menu__content` elements are in the same parent element you can use an `:nth-of-type` selector.

```css
.v-menu__content:nth-of-type(2){
  left: 0.5rem !important;
}
```

Comment: class can be anywhere and im sure the class that has left:12px is not always second from its parent, chances are no class that has left:12px so.. nothing to override